# Retrieve an HTML tag full 'signature'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, dom

Here is the code :

```
parsedHTML = $("<div id=\"foo\">Content</div>");
console.log(parsedHTML);
```

When I run this in Chrome, in the debugger's console I can see

```
[div#foo, jquery: "1.9.1", constructor: function, init: function, selector: "", size: function…]
```

How can I retrieve the first parameter, which is kind of a full name/signature for the HTML element? I mean just the string, not the whole HTML block of code? Like :

```
'div#foo'
```

Comment: That is just a convenience that Chrome devtools provides; it's just hiding a reference to the DOM element within. But it's possible to replicate it in JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want signature like: div#someId.someClass1.someClass2

```
$.prototype.signature = function(){
  return this.prop("tagName").toLowerCase()
   +(this.attr("id") ? "#"+this.attr("id") : "")
   +(this.attr("class") ? "."+this.attr("class").split(/\s+/).join(".") : "");
};
// Div with id="foo" and classes: ["bar", "baz"]
$("#foo").signature();
// "div#foo.bar.baz"
```

Comment: Remove the last concat piece if you only want tag type and id

Comment: I would really have liked a JQuery function to do so, but your answer does it all. Thank you!

Comment: Updated to reflect this extension to $ you wanted - does that work?